# Why lower bound is not working with pairs of vector

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to find upper_bound for pairs of vector.

upper bound for `3` with `vector<int>` is giving me output `4` as expected.

```
int a[] = {2,2,2,2};
vector<int> b(a,a+4);
cout<<(upper_bound(b.begin(), b.end(),3) - b.begin());cout<<endl; //output: 4 as expected
```

For pairs of vector  `vector<pair<int,int>>` upper bound for `make_pair(0,3)` is `0` instead of `4` , I don't understand how?

```
vector<pair<int, int > > v1;
v1.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
v1.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
v1.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
v1.push_back(make_pair(1,2));
cout<<(upper_bound(v1.begin(),v1.end(),make_pair(0,3), sortBySec)-v1.begin())<<endl; // output 0 should be 4
```

I am using `sortBySec` function for considering second value of pair

```
bool sortBySec(pair<int, int> a1,pair<int, int> a2){
    return a1.second - a2.second;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return a1.second - a2.second;` should be `return a1.second < a2.second;`. You are expected to provide *strict weak ordering*, i.e., the `<` relation.